# .htaccess redirect in case of 404 error

Tags: angular, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an angular app with several routes, for example:

```
/collections
/collections/1/1
/servers
/servers/1
```

And my app is placed in `/var/www/html/myapp/`
The **myapp** folder contains the whole project and the index.html file.
In the **index.html** file the **base** is set to    `<base href="/myapp/">`.

And i have a .htaccess file in this folder which contains the rewrite rules

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

When i am trying to enter to http://dummydomain.com/myapp/ it's working fine, but when i enter to http://dummydomain.com/myapp/collections it's not working.

So my question is how can i redirect to index.html when 404 error is directly requested?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RewriteBase` directive and `/` in front of `index.html` will forward requests to site root instead of current directory.

You can use:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L,NC]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```